# how can I add text below shipping text?

Tags: magento2, shipping-address

[image]

I am trying to add one block of text below Shipping Address but do not know where to place it. please help me.

Comment: Your question is similar to below,Check if its helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968411/add-text-into-free-shipping-block-in-checkout-page

Comment: Sorry that is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy a file

```
vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\shipping.html
```

to your theme

```
app/design/frontend/your-theme-package/your-theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html
```

You have to make changes in file Path:

```
app/design/frontend/your-theme-package/your-theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html
```

**After the Line no. 08, you have to add your own text line.**

Then Run Following Commands:

```
php bin/magento s:up && php bin/magento s:d:c && php bin/magento s:s:d -f && php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f
```

Once this works, you need to Overwrite this module in your own module.

Hope this will help you!!